# Residual Unit with ShakeDrop Depth regularization

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, deep-residual-networks

Please I need Python codes for the implementation of a Residual Unit with ShakeDrop Depth regularization.
Here is the design

Design Architecture

[image: 1]